# Why must the Game Loop thread execute in a different thread than the Key Listener?

Tags: multithreading, loops, 2d, java-2d, 2d-games

In the context of threads when executing game loop and key listener threads, why do they must be executed in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the game lib, that you use.

If you have a Chat in your game and the game is lagging and you type something, then you can lost some characters, because of the lag.

BUT: With another Thread the problem is solved, because after the lag, your characters will be sent together!

I mean, the `keylistener` will listen, while your loop is running yes?

Comment: @Richard Telford How about just in general? No Chat or anything causing lag. Why would they be executed in different threads? Any specific reason?

Comment: For example you make an online game
What if someone have a good pc and someone bad pc?
So the guy with the bad pc will be slower, because his input will delay.

Comment: what would be the main issue running both in the same thread?

Comment: Which programming language and which dependency?

Comment: Java... dependency not so important. Why would someone (as per professor) run them both on separate threads? :(